# How to get message count per stream using graylog2 api?

Tags: rest, graylog2

I am trying to get messages count for each stream in Graylog2 using their rest API. But they haven't given any API for that. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just include "streams:58b480a5f1b2518683c8c2bb20" in your query. "58b480a5f1b2518683c8c2bb20" is the stream id in this example.